# Splitting string java

Tags: java, string, split

I've just noticed something strange with the .split() function if I pass a | to it, it splits the string into characters. I tested it with:

```
String s = "Hiya there | how are you | im fine thanks";
for(String str : s.split("|")) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

And it split it into separate characters. I tried backslashing it, it didnt work.

does anyone know how to split it actually by |  ?

Comment: Try adding _two_ backslashes. I know it sounds strange, but...

Comment: Might be interested in this read: http://hoskinator.blogspot.com/2006/11/trouble-using-pipe-with-stringsplit.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String#split` takes a regex as argument, where `|` has a special meaning and is used for `alternation`.

You can use two ways to get yourself out of it: -

1. Escape `|`. Remember, in Java you need to use *double-backslash*: -

   ```
   s.split("\\|");
   ```
2. Use a Character class: -

   ```
   s.split("[|]");
   ```

Inside a character class, any character except `-`, that too when used in the middle, doesn't have any special meaning. So, `[|]` is just a `|` and nothing else.

And yes, you would also need to escape `]` in *character class* as specified in comments by @JanDvorak.

Comment: note that `]` needs to be escaped within a character class as well

Answer (score 2):

`|` is a metacharecter in regex world, in order to treat it as a normal character you would have to escape it with a backslash `\\|`:

```
public static void main(String...args) throws ParseException{
        String s = "Hiya there | how are you | im fine thanks";
        for(String str : s.split("\\|")) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use square brackets with regular expression as they often grow large as new requirements come and with square brackets they are easy to understand compare to backslashes.

```
public static void main(String...args) throws ParseException{
    String s = "Hiya there | how are you | im fine thanks";
    for(String str : s.split("[|]")) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```